# Tensorflow 2+. Using alternative activation functions and custom_gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

To solve differential equations I'm using PINN methodology which uses standard perceptron defined by the function

```
def create_standard_model(layers, activation='tanh', 
                          kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform'):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(layers[0])))
    for i in range(1, len(layers) - 1):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layers[i], activation=activation, 
                                     kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layers[-1], activation='linear'))
    return model
```

During the learning process the next functions are used:

```
def __loss(self, u, u_pred):
    " Loss function "
    f_pred = self.f_model()
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(u - u_pred)) + \
           tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(f_pred))

def __grad(self, X, u):
    " Calculating gradients "
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss_value = self.__loss(u, self.model(X))
    return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, self.model.trainable_variables)

def f_model(self):
    " Calculating gradients and equation residual "
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(self.x_f)                                    
        u = self.model(self.x_f)                                
        u_x = tape.gradient(u, self.x_f)                        
    u_xx = tape.gradient(u_x, self.x_f)                         
    del tape                                                    
    return u_xx - self.x_f_init
```

Fit function:

```
def fit(self, epochs=5000):
    X_u = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_u_global, dtype=self.dtype)
    u = tf.convert_to_tensor(u_global, dtype=self.dtype)
    for epoch in range(epochs):                                 
        loss_value, grads = self.__grad(X_u, u)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.model.trainable_variables))
```

Briefly, in each epoch second derivative according to *x* is calculated. Then, the loss is the sum of equation residual and the boundary condition residual.

So, if I use sigmoidal activation function in my neural network (`activation='tanh'`), the result will be good and there are no problems with my program.

But if I use another activation function, such as softsign (`activation='softsign'`), the LookupError appears:

> LookupError: gradient registry has no entry for: SoftsignGrad

If I understand correctly, there is something wrong with the automatic differentiation and gradients, but I don't know what's exactly should be corrected. Shall I define @tf.custom_gradient function for softsign?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The softsign function doesnt appear in the list of [tensorflow.keras activation function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations). It may have another name.